# Why graphql type relations returns null values?

Tags: axios, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

i have this schema.js of SHIPS

```
// Ships
const ShipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Ships",
  fields: () => ({
    ship_id: { type: GraphQLString },
    ship_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    home_port: { type: GraphQLString },
    ship_type: { type: GraphQLString },
    year_built: { type: GraphQLInt },
    position: { type: ShipPositionType },
    active: { type: GraphQLBoolean }
  })
})

// Ship positions
const ShipPositionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "ShipPositions",
  fields: () => ({
    latitude: { type: GraphQLFloat },
    longitude: { type: GraphQLFloat }
  })
});
```

at ShipType i have added a new field "position" which will return ShipPositionType

this is what i return so far

```
// get ships
    ships: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ShipType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/ships')
          .then(res => res.data);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: if not returned (probably not) from axios/ships response then requires additional resolver for positions

Answer (score 0):

The position field inside the shipType need to have a resolver, inside the resolver you return the ship data based on the ShipType ship_id matching the ShipPositionType ship_id. i.e(`return data.find(ship => ship.shid_id === parent.ship_id )`) . So first add a ship_id field to the ShipPositionType Object.

```
Something like this

// Ships
const ShipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Ships",
  fields: () => ({
    ship_id: { type: GraphQLString },
    ship_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    home_port: { type: GraphQLString },
    ship_type: { type: GraphQLString },
    year_built: { type: GraphQLInt },
    position: {
            type: ShipPositionType,
            resolve(parent,args) {
             return data.find(data => data.ship_id === parent.ship_id)}
           },
     active: { type: GraphQLBoolean }
  })
})

//You need to add a ship_id field here too
// Ship positions
const ShipPositionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "ShipPositions",
  fields: () => ({
    ship_id: {type: {GraphQLString},
    latitude: { type: GraphQLFloat },
    longitude: { type: GraphQLFloat }
  })
});
```